# Finding moment of inertia

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I can see how to compute the moment of inertia around the y-axis of this solid:

The bounds ares: $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$ and $x+y+z=1$.

I'm assuming a constant density, because I have no information about it. I also know that the dinstance form the y-axis is $x^{2}+z^{2}$, but I can't understand how to construct the integral.

Could someone please explain to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\text{moment of inertia}
&=& \displaystyle \rho \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^{1-x-z} (x^2+z^2) \ \mathrm dy \ \mathrm dz \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \rho \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} (1-x-z) (x^2+z^2) \ \mathrm dz \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \rho \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} (-z^3+(1-x)z^2-x^2z+x^2(1-x)) \ \mathrm dz \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \rho \int_0^1 \left(-\dfrac14(1-x)^4+\dfrac13(1-x)^4-\dfrac12x^2(1-x)^2+x^2(1-x)^2\right) \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \rho \int_0^1 \left(\dfrac1{12}(1-x)^4+\dfrac12x^2(1-x)^2\right) \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac\rho{12} \int_0^1 \left((1-x)^4+6x^2(1-x)^2\right) \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac\rho{12} \int_0^1 \left(x^4+6x^2(1-x)^2\right) \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac\rho{12} \int_0^1 \left(x^4+6x^4-12x^3+6x^2\right) \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac\rho{12} \int_0^1 \left(7x^4-12x^3+6x^2\right) \ \mathrm dx \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac\rho{12} \left(\dfrac75-3+2\right) \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac1{30}\rho \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac1{30}\cdot\dfrac{m}{\text{Volume}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac1{30}\cdot\dfrac{m}{\frac16} \\
&=& \displaystyle \dfrac m5 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @DavidQuinn edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found an error in $(1-x)^{4}+6x^{2}(1-x)^{2}=1 - 4 x + 12 x^{2} - 16x^{3} + 7x^{4}$

Comment: @Cosmocrazy read my answer again

Comment: The answer is the same, but I didn't undestand...

Comment: @Cosmocrazy I changed $\displaystyle\int_0^1 (1-x)^4 \ \mathrm dx$ to $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^4 \ \mathrm dx$. (Why can I do this?)

Comment: You change the variable! Why is $v=1/6$?

Comment: @Cosmocrazy It is a tetrahedron generated by (0,0,1), (0,1,0), and (1,0,0).